# Cribbage beginner "Go" questions

Tags: cribbage

I found this explnation of "Go" on the Bicycle cards website https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/cribbage/

*"THE GO
During play, the running total of cards may never be carried beyond 31. If a player cannot add another card without exceeding 31, he or she says "Go" and the opponent pegs 1. After gaining the Go, the opponent must first lay down any additional cards he can without exceeding 31. Besides the point for Go, he may then score any additional points that can be made through pairs and runs (described later). If a player reaches exactly 31, he pegs two instead of one for Go.
The player who called Go leads for the next series of plays, with the count starting at zero. The lead may not be combined with any cards previously played to form a scoring combination; the Go has interrupted the sequence.
The person who plays the last card pegs one for Go, plus one extra if the card brings the count to exactly 31. The dealer is sure to peg at least one point in every hand, for he will have a Go on the last card if not earlier."*

So my understanding is...

The Play:

1) Non-dealer lays for first round of Play and cards are layed, counting as play proceeds. 
2) If a player cannot add another card without exceeding 31, he or she says "Go" and the opponent pegs 1

What happens if the opponent can't lay a card to bring the score to either 31 or under 31?
What happens if the oppponent lays a card and brings the total to under 31?
What happens if the oppponent lays a card and brings the total to 31?

3) Spent cards are turned over as these can not count towards the next round of Play
4) The player who previously called Go leads for the next series of plays, with the count starting at zero.

What would happen if for example, the player who previously called "Go" has no cards to put down to lead?

Or what would happen if for example, the player who previously called "Go" is the only player with cards left?

Lead's cards to play = A,7,A,6/K
Opponent's cards to play = 5,k,Q,Q

Lead A (1), Opp 5 (6), Lead 7 (13), Opp K (23), Lead A (24), Opp Go.

If Lead 6 (30) then lead pegs 1. Lead now has no cards to play. What happens at this point, as opponent has two Qs left?

However, say where Lead has a K to play instead of a 6, then

Lead A (1), Opp 5 (6), Lead 7 (13), Opp K (23), Lead Go.

At this point, the Opponent can't lay either Q. So are any points given?

Answer (score 1):

In order:

**- What happens if the opponent can't lay a card to bring the score to either 31 or under 31?**
 *Nothing; that's normal. The **Go** stands.*

**- What happens if the opponent lays a card and brings the total to under 31?**
 *Nothing; that's normal again. The **Go** stands.*

**- What happens if the opponent lays a card and brings the total to 31?**
 *Opponent gets 2 for **Thirty One** instead of the already scored **Go**.*

*Alternately, think of it as getting a second point for the **Thirty One** being reached exactly.*

**- What would happen if for example, the player who previously called "Go" has no cards to put down to lead?**
 *As in any other circumstance, that's another **Go** and opponent can play any remaining cards in hand as desired to maximize pegging value.*

**- Or what would happen if for example, the player who previously called "Go" is the only player with cards left?**
 *Same as before, but reversed.*

**- What happens at this point, as opponent has two Qs left?**
 *Opponent plays Q(10), Q(20) for **Pair** (two points) and **Last Card** (one point, functionally identical to **go** but called differently.)*

**- At this point, the Opponent can't play either Q. So are any points given?**
 *This is the default situation. Opponent scores the **Go**, and starts off the next sequence once already played cards have been turned over.*

---

To remember the correct technique note that the proper timing for scoring a **Go** is once **neither player** can play anymore cards. At this moment in time, the last player to have played one or more cards gets either two points (if the count is exactly 31) or one point (if the count is less than 31).

The [American Cribbage Congress Tournament Rules](http://www.cribbage.org/NewSite/rules/default.asp) hint, but don't quite make explicit, this interpretation (**my emphasis**):

- From the [Scoring Chart](http://www.cribbage.org/NewSite/rules/rule1.asp#section7)

  [image]
- From [**Rule 7.2 Scoring**](http://www.cribbage.org/NewSite/rules/rule7.asp)

  > **a)** Points are earned during the play of the cards for the following single card or combination of consecutive cards played. **The player playing the last card that forms a combination earns the points** (see scoring chart in Rule 1.7):
  >
  > ...
  >
  > (7) a cumulative count of 31
  >
  > (8) the final card played, not making a cumulative count of 31
  >
  > **b)** ... When a player's opponent has no more cards or calls "go," the other player may play all playable cards in succession and announce the points scored before **pegging the total at one time**.

So it is *the combination of all cards played in this series after the opponent has last played a card* that scores either two for **Thirty One** or one for whichever of **Go** or **Last Card** applies.